# Why does hiding content for print seem to resize my document?

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have an issue & a solution, but I would like to know the why. I am creating a  table for print & I am hiding some content inside the `<th/>` when printing. When this done the entire page seems to grow in size & nothing fits on the page anymore. It is not as if the columns of the `<table/>` grow or shrink in size & the `<table/>` grows to accommodate; it is the entire site's page.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```css
#tell_con > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.54em .77em 0 .77em;
}
#tell_con thead {
  background-color: #666;
}
#tell_con tbody {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
#tell_con th,
#tell_con td {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .231em 1.155em;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
thead {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #FFF;
}
th {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 95%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: .539em .77em;
}
th > span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
tbody {
  table-layout: fixed;
  background-color: #E6E6FF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
tr {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td {
  white-space: noramal;
  padding: .385em .77em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(1) td {
  border-top: none;
}
td:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
@media print {
  /* This is the line of code that seems to cause the issue, other properties that caused the issue are the following: {font-size:0;} {width:0; height:0;} The fix to prevent the issue was {position:absolute; opacity:0;}. */
  th > span {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Code to change the Column Header */
  th[col_name="one"]:before {
    content: 'Col 1';
  }
  th[col_name="two"]:before {
    content: 'Col 2';
  }
  th[col_name="three"]:before {
    content: 'Col 3';
  }
  th[col_name="four"]:before {
    content: 'Col 4';
  }
  th[col_name="five"]:before {
    content: 'Col 5';
  }
  th[col_name="six"]:before {
    content: 'Col 6';
  }
  th[col_name="seven"]:before {
    content: 'Col 7';
  }
  th[col_name="eight"]:before {
    content: 'Col 8';
  }
  th[col_name="nine"]:before {
    content: 'Col 9';
  }
  th[col_name="ten"]:before {
    content: 'Col 10';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='tell_con'>
  <div id='data_con_1'>
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>0-30</th>
          <th>30-45</th>
          <th>46-60</th>
          <th>&gt;=61</th>
          <th>Other</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='data_con_2'>
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Data Container 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='data_con_3'>
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Data Container 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='data_con_4'>
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Data Container 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span>0</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th col_name='one'><span>Column Header 1</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='two'><span>Column Header 2</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='three'><span>Column Header 3</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='four'><span>Column Header 4</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='five'><span>Column Header 5</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='six'><span>Column Header 6</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='seven'><span>Column Header 7</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='eight'><span>Column Header 8</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='nine'><span>Column Header 9</span>
      </th>
      <th col_name='ten'><span>Column Header 10</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Column Header 1</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 2</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 3</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 4</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 5</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 6</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 7</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 8</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 9</span>
      </td>
      <td><span>Column Header 10</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would post a picture but I am unable to do so. But you can try my code out in a snippet, in your site; there are many ways. Let me know what else may be helpful & any thoughts you have regarding this issue.

UPDATE: I forgot to specify the relative parent to the th > span as the th. Giving `th{position:relative;}` causes with the 'fix' of `th > span{position:absolute; opacity:0;}` shows the same results as using the other properties that cause the 'issue'.

My question still remains as to why the entire page is re-sized.

Comment: Is it a typo in the `td:before` rule where it's written `display:inline-bloc`?

Comment: I can confirm that is not the issue. I had to rewrite out all this code blind, on a small screen. All of my code is being rendered properly, the issue does not appear until print when the td > span is hidden by any of the following properties: {display:none;} {font-size:0;} {width:0; height:0;}

Comment: This code is wrong `display: inline-block height: 100%;`, it misses a semicolon `;` after _block_ and should be `display: inline-block; height: 100%;`, and I am not saying this is the cause but it cause issue itself